# What is the difference between the Sallen-Key and VCVS topologies?

Tags: filter, sallen-key, topology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology#Explanation_of_operation), the Sallen-Key is a special case of the VCVS (voltage-controlled voltage-source) filter topology in which the gain is unitary.

The topology is:
[image]

The [VCVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology#Application:_bandpass_filter) refers to the [non-unitary](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/%7Ethomas/ee322_s09/labs/vcvs_filter.html) version:

[image]

The book *Linear Circuit Design Handbook* [says](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/sallen-key) that:

> The Sallen–Key configuration, also known as a voltage control voltage source (VCVS), was first introduced in 1955 by R.P. Sallen and E.L. Key of MIT's Lincoln Labs (see Reference 14).

What is the difference between Sallen-Key and VCVS topologies?

Comment: But isn't the key difference already mentioned in the Wikipedia article you quoted?

Comment: @Justme but the book *Linear Circuit Design Handbook* contradicts such a difference claiming that both are the same thing.

Comment: There is no contradiction. If the Sallen-Key is also a VCVS, but it may be that it's a special case of a generic VCVS with gain of 1 that can be called a Sallen-Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

The Sallen-Key topology is also a VCVS topology, but Sallen and Key implemented it with electron tubes that were operating in unity gain cathode follower configuration.

So the Sallen-Key filter is a special case of generic VCVS filter which has the gain set to unity, i.e. it uses a buffer.